# Relation between $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{I}f_n(x)\:dx$ and $\int_{I}\lim_{n \to \infty}f(x)\:dx$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Relation between convergence and integration of sequence of a function.

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of integrable functions defined on an closed interval with

> $$f_n(x) \to 0$$

on this interval

Then what will be its integration on that closed interval?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SE.  __2__ things: I have reformatted your post but the input interpretation may be wrong so in future use
 [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?lq=1) to learn how to format via $\LaTeX$ and secondly, 
if someone gives an answer that is useful to you don't forget to tick it. All the best.

Answer (score 1):

If the convergence, as $n \to \infty$, 
$$
f_n(x) \to f(x), \quad x \in I,
$$ is just a **pointwise convergence**, then in general when it makes sense:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{I}f_n(x)\:dx \neq \int_{I}\lim_{n \to \infty}f(x)\:dx.
$$
For example, consider $f_n: \,[0,1]\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f_n(x)=nx(1-x^2)^n$, we have 
$$
f_n(x) \to 0, \quad x \in [0,1],
$$ but $$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_0^1f_n(x) dx=\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_0^1nx(1-x^2)^n dx=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n}{2n+2}=\frac12\neq0.
$$

A sufficient condition for switching limit and integration is **[uniform convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence)** over $I$.

Comment: Just happened upon this question. Your calculation isn't quite right: $\int_0^1x(1-x^2)^n\,dx\neq\frac{n}{2n+2}$. Rather, the integral is $\frac{1}{2n+2}$, which does in fact tend to zero. So your sequence of functions is not the counterexample you want. One fix would be $f_n(x)=nx^n(1-x^n)$.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Thank you! Typo corrected (same function is OK, a factor $n$ was missing).

Comment: oh yes, duh; your fix is the easiest fix.